# Get object IN a model with particular field value OR NOT IN a related model

Tags: python, django, django-orm

am new to django so complex querying is becoming difficult.

> I have a model `Animal` and `Heat` i would like to fetch an Animal
>   instance with `farm=1` **AND** `sex='female'` **AND** an Animal
>   instance with `Heat.is_active=True` **AND** `Heat.is_bred=False`

Here is my models.

```
class Animal(models.Model):

    farm = models.ForeignKey(Farm, related_name='farm_animals', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=7)

class Heat(models.Model):

    animal = models.ForeignKey(Animal, related_name='heats', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    is_bred = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

So far i tried this query:

```
    Animal.objects.filter(
        farm=1, sex='female',
        heats__is_active=True,
        heats__is_bred=False
    )
```

I can fetch a data if an animal instance **HAS HEAT RECORD** however i can't fetch any when there is **NO HEAT RECORD**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **OR** between the two pairs of conditions using the `Q()` object:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Animal.objects.filter(
    (Q(farm=1) & Q(sex='female')) | 
    (Q(heats__is_active=True) & Q(heats__is_bred=False))
)
```

This will give you a queryset containing animals that don't even have a `Heat` record.

Comment: @Evans_Murithi do you have a gmail?

Comment: I appreciate it sir